# How can I modify the border/margin for radio buttons inside a wellpanel in Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I want to have something like 10px padding/difference/margin from the wellPanel in Shiny for my radioButtons but right now they are connected to the line depicting the wellPanel as shown in this photo. Any idea how to fix it?

[image]

Here's the code I have:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  theme = "bootstrap.css",
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "bootstrap.css")
  ),

 div(class="set1", list(tags$head(HTML('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/WUYdxrH.png"
                      style="border:100px width="1600"  height="100"
                      alt="FML Toolkit" />')))),
 sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(width = 6,

      wellPanel(fluidRow(
        column(5, radioButtons("dbterm", "Database Type", c("Normalized", "Denormalized")))
        )),
        fluidRow(
        column(7, uiOutput("ui0"))
        ),
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this line maybe will help you:

```
 style = "border: 10px",
```

to be like this:

```
wellPanel(fluidRow(
    column(5, radioButtons("dbterm", "Database Type", c("Normalized", "Denormalized"))),

    style = "border: 10px",
    )),
    fluidRow(
    column(7, uiOutput("ui0"))
    ),
```

Comment: It doesn't work and gives me this error: `ERROR: /Users/mona/CS764/demo/1a/ui.R:17:20: unexpected symbol
16:                    
17:                    style
                       ^`

Comment: I don't konw if this will help you or not. But i found this tutorial that talks about making UI in Shiny. I don't know maybe you what to see it and other lessons too. http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson2/

Comment: @MonaJalal That's because there was a comma missing.